# DB side changes merge issue between Git branches

Tags: git, merge, branch, liquibase, conflict

In our web application we have multiple branches like develop, release etc. The developers check in DB side changes in changes.sql file with Liquibase changeset IDs and commit them in develop branch. For example, changes.sql file in develop branch:

- Changeset id:1
- Some SQL Query
- Changeset id:2
- Some SQL Query

Now, when the code finilasized what we do is we create a new release branch from develop and create a new BUILD to provide in production. So now the changes.sql file will also be available in release branch.

In the meantime, the developers will continue to work in develop branch for new features and will add new changeset IDs in changes.sql file. For example as shown below:

- Develop Changeset id:1
- Some SQL Query
- Develop Changeset id:2
- Some SQL Query
- Develop Changeset id:3
- Some SQL Query

and they commit and push to develop branch. In the meantime, some developers will also check in on release branch to fix bugs on release build, so they also make changes in released branch changes.sql file. like below:

- Release Changeset id:1
- Some SQL Query
- Release Changeset id:2
- Some SQL Query

Now, ultimately after few days when we merge release branch changes to develop branch we face ordering issues in changes.sql file. Like I said, now the changes.sql file becomes like this:

- Develop Changeset id:1
- Some SQL Query
- Develop Changeset id:2
- Some SQL Query
- Develop Changeset id:3
- Some SQL Query
- Release Changeset id:1
- Some SQL Query
- Release Changeset id:2
- Some SQL Query
- Develop Changeset id:4
- New SQL Query

We want that the release changesets should always be in top of any develop changeset in changes.sql file every time we merge. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're unhappy with the auto-merge you could just do it manually. You simply need to edit the file after the merge begins, but before the merge is completed. If there is a conflict during the merge that it can't auto-resolve, then it already stops and gives you a chance to edit the file before committing the merge. But if it doesn't stop because it auto-resolves, then you can force it to stop by adding the `--no-commit` option:

```
git merge release --no-commit
```

Now you should be able to inspect your changes.sql file and modify it if desired. When you're done, you can continue with:

```
git merge --continue
```

Comment: Thanks but we can not do it manually any suggestions if we want to do it automatically without conflicts?

Comment: @JanakrayDudhrejiya maybe you could just write a script to automate putting it in the order you'd like?

Comment: Also, check out `git rerere`. It may be applicable in your situation.